# Get list of currently active/ logged in users in asp identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC 5's identity in order to allow users to login to my site.

Within my admin panel, I was thinking of including a list of all users that were currently logged in, and so have added a 'isLoggedIn' bit value within my UsersTable.

However, I can't seem to think of a way in order to 'fill this in' in such a way that it will update automatically when user

- logs in (logged in, 1)
- logs out (logged out, 0)
- closes window (logged out, 0)
- is idle for a long time (~2 hours) (logged out, 0)

The 'logout' and 'login' are quite straight forward (updating this table within the login/logout actionresults). However, I'm at a slight loss as to how to handle the other issues (closing window, idle).

I was initially thinking of either adding a method to every actionresult to 'increase a timeout' before auto updating the column to 0 - but this seems quite/very inefficient, nor does it sound like very good practise.

Is there a 'set way' of doing this in asp identity? Or is there an efficient way of doing this? Once the table auto updates, it'll be easy enough - but I can't seem to think of a way of seeing if user has closed the browser, or sat there idle (which, I suppose, sort of leads to the question 'are they logged in or not?' or 'should i have a logout timeout anyway?')

Any advise on this would be much appreciated, anyway.

Comment: The idle one might be something to add to the global.asax.cs in the application lifecycle  . [Lifecycle doc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) . I know the `RequestNotification` has `ReleaseRequestState` which might be useful, and `AuthorizeRequest` . You could also add a _isCurrentlyLoggedIn_ bool column on the AspNetUsers table that is written to when  `PasswordSignInAsync` &&  `AuthenticationManager.SignOut();` are hit , in the AccountController